# Как сервер выдает порт клиенту? Или как клиент узнает порт сервера?

Tags: сервер, клиент-сервер, tcp-ip, port

Я правильно понимаю, что клиент отправляет запрос на определенный IP-адрес, а порт выдает уже сам сервер?..т.е чтобы отправить запрос, не обязательно указывать порт назначения?

Comment: как клиент узнает порт сервера?. Каким образом? Ведь DNS сообщает только IP-адрес..

Comment: мы вводим в адресную строку название сайта vk.com. Как к этому сайту (IP-адресу) пририсовывается порт?

Comment: но как моя машина узнает порт vk.com? Или вк на порту 80 сидит?

Comment: в браузере адресная строка

Answer (score 2):

Порт -- обязательная часть клиент-серверного взаимодействия в сетях TCP/IP. Возьмём самый распространённый протокол http: За протоколом http, по умолчанию, закреплён порт 80, за SSL/TLS версией http -- порт 443, поэтому, когда мы набираем в браузере vk.com, без указания порта, браузер уже знает, что надо устанавливать соединение с ip адресом сервера vk.com, на 80-м порту. Если набрать https://vk.com, то будут попытки соединения уже на 443 порт. На самом деле в адресной строке нужно указывать порт, если сервис висит на нестандартном порту.
[image: Пример]

Comment: т.е. если я изменю у своего приложения порт с 80 на 1524, то клиент просто не сможет загрузить в браузере мой сайт?..

Comment: @Ivan Сможет, если укажет 1524-й порт, через двоеточие, как на скриншоте.

Comment: но если не укажет, то будет ошибка сервера?

Comment: @Ivan Клиента. Ошибка клиента. Если на 80-м порту ничего не висит, то и некому выдавать какие-либо ошибки.